# Spring Boot and Spring Integration does not fit together

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-integration

I have a short question. We are using spring integration in our project and faced a problem after Upgrading the spring boot version. The threadpool size is 1 instead of 10 per default.

I analysed it and found out the following:

The problem is that with the newer version with autoconfiguration (https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/blob/cd018aff9c65009d5e0ba47f48fa748eac6bff12/spring-boot-project/spring-boot-autoconfigure/src/main/java/org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/integration/IntegrationAutoConfiguration.java) a ThreadPoolTaskScheduler is initialized Line 174 if none exists, but with 0 configuration. Then when we use spring-boot-starter-integration normally with the following class (https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-integration/blob/c4ee5512f6f7170ada43af4f1167d74adb2e0dd2/spring-integration-core/src/main/java/org/springframework/integration/config/DefaultConfiguringBeanFactoryPostProcessor.java) also a TaskScheduler is configured Line 286, but this time with PoolSize 10. But because there already exists a TaskScheduler in ApplicationContext not a second one is created and the threadPoolSize stays on 1.

My question is now:
Why does spring-boot has to create a TaskScheduler on its own when it will be also created by spring-integration itself?Is it the responsibility of Spring Boot to create it?

I made a example project: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1xmDpZ5SmQlNN948uoyQun91JJ0AkTq-F/view?usp=sharing

These are my Breakpoints in IntegrationAutoConfiguration.java and DefaultConfiguringBeanFactoryPostProcessor.java.

I expected that the Breakpoint in DefaultConfiguringBeanFactoryPostProcessor.java get reached but it does not.
[DefaultConfiguringBeanFactoryPostProcessor.java](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ikDyX.png)
[IntegrationAutoConfiguration.java](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GQL8K.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `TaskScheduler` is needed not only for Spring Integration.
For example see `@EnableScheduling` in Spring Framework: https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/reference/integration/scheduling.html. There are also might be many other places where we would need to schedule some tasks without Spring Integration involved.

Since `TaskScheduler` is crucial for Spring Integration polling endpoints, it creates one for us automatically without Spring Boot - for convenience.

Since Spring Boot is a framework for microservices it was a sane choice to have a pool for that `TaskScheduler` as `1` - one task per service, but properly. When Spring Integration is involved in Spring Boot environment, it just honors whatever is there auto-configured. For consistency with Spring Boot best practice.

If one thread is not enough for your in that pool, you can provide a respective configuration property - `spring.task.scheduling.pool.size=10`: https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#features.task-execution-and-scheduling.

Comment: Does IntegrationAutoConfiguration.java has something to do with spring-integration?

Comment: This means that @EnableScheduling also calls @EnableIntegration? To have a TaskScheduler which would be configured in IntegrationAutoConfiguration.java?

Comment: In spring-integration the TaskScheduler which would be created here, has more Properties which are configured compared to the plain TaskScheduler in Spring Boot.
  Would it make sense to also configure them in application.yml? For example ("threadNamePrefix", "task-scheduler-")

Comment: The `IntegrationAutoConfiguration` does that `@EnableIntegration` for us indeed. And some other stuff which can be based on Spring Boot but relevant for Spring Integration. See that JavaDoc, for example: `Expose a standard {@link ThreadPoolTaskScheduler} if the user has not enabled task scheduling explicitly.`

Comment: What? You didn't read that doc in Spring Boot? There is indeed that prefix property there: `spring.task.scheduling.thread-name-prefix=scheduling-`